# PHP: Extract individual parts of all filenames of files within a dir

Tags: php, string, file

I'd like to be able to loop over all of the files within a directory (the one the script is in) and extract portions of the name and turn it into CSV readable.

From:

```
ch-026-Metallic-Morphing Mauve-14pt.jpg
```

To:

```
ch-026, Metallica-Morphing Mauve-14pt
```

...or however Excel or Numbers would be able to read it.

---

At the request of a couple of you, I'll clarify that I want to cut out the second "-" dash and replace it with a comma and space.

Comment: Please, improve your question.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa - How do you want the OP to improve the question?

Comment: I would start by learning the SPL directory iterator class and/or glob command php.net/glob

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa, how in the world could I possibly make it any simpler to understand? I want to parse out the name into a string separated by a comma... or however is best for CSV.

Comment: For example, define "portion"! How many chars is a "portion"?

Comment: Actually, you could be more explicit. For example. Do all entries begin with the sequence 'ch-026'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use

```
$fileList = scandir( $directoryPath );
```

to scan the directory. Then loop like this

```
foreach( $fileList as $fileName ) {
 ...
}
```

Finally, use [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match entries. Generally:

```
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, fileName, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

In your case a pattern like

```
$pattern = '/^ch-\d*-(.*)-\d*pt\.jpg$/';
```

might do the job.

Finally, use the information provided in $matches to write the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can "extract portions of the name and turn it into CSV readable" to match your example using regexp:

```
$csv_contents .= preg_replace('/^([^-]+-[^-]+)-(.+)\.jpg$/','\1, \2',$filename)."\n";
```

`$filename` may be obtained using Stefan Pantke's script.